# Giving new ID for selection in Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I would like to give a new ID to selection . Here is the code:

```
 var len=(table.rows.length); //say this will result 6
 var newid="agentID"+len;
 var new_optionAgent =
 "<select class=\"opsi\"id=newid>"
+"<option selected=\"selected\"disabled=\"disabled\">Agent<\/option>"
+"<option value=\"agentA\">Agent A<\/option>"
+"<option value=\"agentB\">Agent B<\/option>"
+"<option value=\"agentC\">Agent C<\/option>"
+"<option value=\"agentD\">Agent D<\/option>"
+"<\/select>"
```

and I make another function to test the id by alert its value

```
var test=document.getElementById("agentGroup6").value;
alert(test);
```

It should return "Agent" to me when alert. But it doesn't work. Any way to solve this? Thank you b4

Comment: Try moving the disabled attribute to the select-tag

Comment: why are you using `getElementById("agentGroup6")` instead of `getElementById("agentID6")`

Comment: `'<select class="opsi" id="'+newid+'">'` - use string concatenation

Comment: getElementById("agentID6") it should be. Sorry wrong copy

Comment: What happens to `new_optionAgent`? It's only being assigned and not read. What element has the ID `agentGroup6`? You could provide a snippet or a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with some complete code.

Comment: Thanks Johny ! It works :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your select tag to this:

```
"<select class=\"opsi\"id=\""+newid+"\">"
```